# Delete child nodes

Tags: javascript

On my Greenhouse jobboard, there are some links that allow applicants to upload their CV from Dropbox. I need to remove the Dropbox link. I can identify the child nodes with `document.getElementsByClassName("link-container")` but can anyone help delete the one where `data-source="dropbox"`?

```html
<div class="link-container">
    <a data-source="attach" href="#">Attach</a>

      <a data-source="dropbox" href="#">Dropbox</a>
      <a data-source="google-drive" href="#">Google Drive</a>

      <a data-source="paste" href="#">Paste</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest – using ES6 `Array.from()` and arrow functions – the following:

```js
// assuming there might be more than one element to be removed from
// the document, here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve
// all <a> elements with a 'data-source' attribute equal to 'dropbox':
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-source=dropbox]');

// we convert the NodeList from document.querySelectorAll() into an
// an Array in order to use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate
// over the elements:
Array.from(targets).forEach(

  // now we use an Arrow function expression to access the
  // current array-element of the array over which we're 
  // iterating (the 'dropboxLink' variable), and then
  // perform the expression following the fat arrow ('=>')
  // for each element of the array; finding the parentNode
  // and removing that child from the parentNode:
  dropboxLink => dropboxLink.parentNode.removeChild(dropboxLink));
```

```html
<div class="link-container">
  <a data-source="attach" href="#">Attach</a>

  <a data-source="dropbox" href="#">Dropbox</a>
  <a data-source="google-drive" href="#">Google Drive</a>

  <a data-source="paste" href="#">Paste</a>
</div>
```

Without ES6 it's a little more verbose:

```js
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-source=dropbox]');


// using function.prototype.call() to allow us to use
// Array.prototype.slice() on the array-like NodeList,
// converting it into an Array:
Array.prototype.slice.call(targets)

  // using Array.prototype.forEach:
  .forEach(function(dropboxLink) {
    // 'dropboxLink' refers to the current Array element
    // of the Array over which we're iterating.

    // and, again, we remove the current Array-element
    // from its parentNode:
    dropboxLink.parentNode.removeChild(dropboxLink);
});
```

```html
<div class="link-container">
  <a data-source="attach" href="#">Attach</a>

  <a data-source="dropbox" href="#">Dropbox</a>
  <a data-source="google-drive" href="#">Google Drive</a>

  <a data-source="paste" href="#">Paste</a>
</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).

Comment: The ES6 option isn't available to me but the non-ES6 one worked perfectly - thanks!